# Hide HTML5 Audio/Video notification in Android Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-audio

I have an HTML5 Audio element on my web app. At some point, I programmatically stop the playback, using this code:

```is
   audioElement.pause();
   audioElement.currentTime = 0;
```

When the audio is playing, there is a notification on my Android device (using Google Chrome). I would expect this notification to disappear once I stop the playback, but it doesn't.

How do I remove the notification?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by setting src attribute to blank and load it again. below is line of code

audioElement.setAttribute('src', '');
audioElement.load();

it worked for me for Video element but for same problem. Happy Coding.....

Answer (score 1):

Below code works for me

```
audioElement.pause();
audioElement.currentTime = 0;
audioElement.load();
```

Comment: `audioElement.currentTime = 0;` is probably not required as `audioElement.load()` resets it.