# Stop audio notification from appearing on mobile Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, html5-video, avconv

I am using an HTML5 video tag as follows:

```
    <video playsInline muted autoPlay className='video' preload='auto' loop='loop'>
      <source src="intro-m-no-audio.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
    </video>
```

As you can see, the `muted` attribute is set. Also, I made sure the video doesn't have any more audio track:

```
avconv -i intro-m.mp4 -vcodec copy -an intro-m-no-audio.mp4
```

this gives:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'intro-m-no-audio.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2017-04-13 15:01:27
    encoder         : Lavf53.21.1
  Duration: 00:00:08.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2104 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p, 960x540 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2102 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-04-13 15:01:27
```

As you can see, there is no more audio stream present.

YET, everytime I open the page on Android Mobile Firefox (v53), my Spotify player stops playing and an annoying video "notification" appears. That doesn't happen in Chrome (on Android). How can I prevent this?

**EDIT**: Here's the live example to see what I mean: https://www.srf.ch/static/srf-data/data/2017/pendler/#/de

Comment: This seems similar to another post, does this post address your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40843798/hide-html5-audio-video-notification-in-android-chrome  ?

Comment: Mh, not really. I don't think so, because I don't want to appear any notification at all.

Comment: Seems like a bug in Firefox. You might try scanning for issues on bugzilla https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/describecomponents.cgi?product=Firefox%20for%20Android

Comment: I'm having this issue in Chrome. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.